# Struts url tag to retrieve a list

Tags: jsp, url, struts2, checkboxlist

I would like to retrieve a list of checkboxes and load it on the current page.
One way to do it is to call the action class and then load the page.
I am trying to do the same using **s:url** I am not sure if this is even possible.

JSP code for level_zero_grant_access.jsp

```
<s:url id="idCheckBoxList" action="LoadBusinessCheckBoxes" var="idcb"/>
    <div id="idAccessInfo" style="">
        Select Business <br>                        
        <s:checkboxlist list="%{idcb.businessCb}" name="checkboxes" />
    </div>
```

Struts.xml

```
        <action name="LoadCheckBoxes"
        class="admin_module.action.LoadCheckBoxes" method="execute">
        <result name="success"> /Admin_Pages/level_zero_grant_access.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

Action class has getters and setters and execute method where i prepare a map with the name businessCb

Comment: The `<s:url>` isn't for executing actions. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to load checkboxlist. So the only way to do it is call the action first and then load the page. Correct?

Comment: The `url` is a control tag that renders a valid URL string.

Comment: Not it is not the only way. But if you don't have *some special* requirements  then it is the easiest way.

Comment: Agreed and we use it with ajax tags like autocompleter. Therefore I was hoping I could use it with non ajax tags as well. I think the ajax code makes an explicit call to the action specified in the url

Comment: @AleksandrM can you please point me to the alernative ways

Comment: So why don't you want to call and action and in action method populate a list?

Comment: that is what I am currently doing. Just wanted to see if I directly go to a page and then on page load the page will call some actions.

Comment: Don't allow to go directly to page. Pages should be accessible only through actions.